# How to install libavcodec and libavutil from its source in linux

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, ffmpeg

FFMPEG is providing `libavutil` and `libavcodec` libraries. While compiling and installing `ffmpeg` as described at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu I can find `libavcodec` and `libavutil` folders in the `ffmpeg` source folder. I want to install these libraries to use them in my c++ programs. But there are no Makefiles in these folders. How can I install them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply type `make install` in the root (top-level) folder, which contains the [install](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=Makefile;h=f3bd5f682defffdf4ac44e8be3a645ccb0def33f;hb=HEAD#l148) target.

Comment: @neckTwi The very first sentence on the guide says "this guide [...] will provide a local install of the latest FFmpeg tools **and libraries**".

Answer (score 1):

Using that guide, ffmpeg is built and installed with

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig"
--prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build"
--extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include"
--extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib"
```

So, all of ffmpeg libraries get installed, but they're installed inside `/home/username/ffmpeg_build/lib` and `/home/username/ffmpeg_build/include`. As well, if you compiled this as root, I believe they would be inside /root and inaccessible to users and other programs.

And those directories are not normally included in any PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH, so when you try to build something that uses those libraries, it'll be unlikely to find them, unless you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.